# Layer disappears when zooming out past certain point in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, zoom

I have shared several layers from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Online, and one of the layers disappears when I zoom out past a certain point in the map (1:320,000). All of the layers work as they should in ArcGIS Pro. The other layers (with the similar settings) resize when I zoom in and out, and all of the layers have the same visibility range. The layer I have problems with changes symbology from a thin line (1:160,000-1:80,000), a strange lump-shape (1:40,000-5,000), towards correct shape and extent at 1:2,500.

I have checked the Spatial Index and Check Geometry.

What else can I do?

Comment: Do you have a web map we could take a look at?

Comment: Take a look at: https://arcg.is/1PT4HT

Its the layer "Planlagte veganlegg bru" that I have problems with, and "Planlagte veganlegg Gang/Sykkelveg" and "Planlagte veganlegg UtbedringVeg" are working. "Bru veganlegg ny5" is another attempt of sharing the "Planlagte veganlegg bru" layer from ArcGIS Pro and importing it.

Let me know if you need more information or have problems with the map

Comment: I am not seeing that happen.  I have only "Planlagte veganlegg bru" active. When I zoom out so that the RF is smaller than 1:320,000 I can still see the layer on the map, even though it is very small, and it does not grey out as it would if you had exceeded the visibility range set for the layer.  The feature disappears at 1:1,280,000 and beyond but it is still there but this is simply because it is too small to see.  As for its morphing to a lump and then a thin line as you decrease scale, that appears to be due to the fact that it is too small to hold any shape at those scales.

Comment: Please let me know if I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: I have had the same thought considering the size of the object, that the objects are too small to visualize from distance. But in ArcGIS Pro its different, there its possible to visualize similar to the other layers, independedly of how much you zoom in and out.

Comment: I downloaded the layer into ArcGIS Pro.  I do not see what you are describing.  When I decrease the RF to beyond 1:125,000 it disappears.  Perhaps someone else here can speak to why this is happening.